# Dojo template instantiated manually and populated with JSON data

Tags: dojo

I am trying to use templates in Dojo but no matter what I do, I can not get one instantiated in code to produce any result. I've tried following the few examples I've found online, but frankly, I can't find a good end to end example.

So far I have a DOM element:

```
<div id='services'></div>
```

that I want to populate with an HTML fragment that is generated from this class:

```
require([
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
  "dojo/text!app/templates/service.html"
],
  function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template) {

    declare("service",
      [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: template,
        constructor: function () {
            // summary:
            //    description
            console.log("Class is a " + this.declaredClass);
        },
        name:'',
        url:''
    });
});
```

The HTML fragment/template looks like this:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="${name}" value=""/>
  <span class="layerToggle">${name}</span>
</label>
```

I call it in another method like this:

```
function populateServices() {
  var serviceUrl = 'https://services.example.com/services?token=' + auth.token;
  utils.getJson(serviceUrl).then(function(json) {
      for (var i = 0; i < json.services.length; i++) {
        var serviceItem = new service({
          name: json.services[i].name,
          url: json.services[i].url
        });
        console.log(serviceItem); //doesn't fire or empty
        domConstruct.place(serviceItem, "services", "last");
      };
    });
  }
```

The class does get instantiated once, but nothing else works.

Does anyone see any problems? Or am I WAY off base with how a template should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost correctly. The problem is that your widget is not a DOM node, so the following code will fail:

```js
domConstruct.place(serviceItem, "services", "last");
```

When creatin a widget instance programatically, you can provide 2 parameters. The first one are the options like you provided them:

```js
{
    name: json.services[i].name,
    url: json.services[i].url
}
```

The second parameter is the DOM node it should use to be placed at. You should use that second parameter to put the widget on your DOM, for example:

```js
var serviceItem = new service({
    name: json.services[i].name,
    url: json.services[i].url
}, domConstruct.create("label", null, "services", "last"));
```

Then you don't need to use the `domConstruct.place` anymore. You can see the result at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/9d3pb/).

---

Another possibility is just by simply using the `domNode` property, for example:

```js
domConstruct.place(serviceItem.domNode, "services", "last");
```

As a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/9d3pb/1/

---

**NOTE**: I could execute your code and the `console.log()` would work fine as well. So I assume there might be some other problems as well which you need to fix. Verify that you correctly imported your service widget and that your service has the correct JSON response.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you learn that? It works now, I appreciate your help. This example: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/recipes/custom_widget/ didn't work at all. (They use placeAt and it does nothing at all)

Comment: But the odd thing is, I can do it like your jsFiddle does. But as soon as I try to include it into my entire program, it won't work. It only works if I do everything inside of the file with the declaration. (like you've done)

Comment: Are you sure your DOM is loaded when you try to add your service widgets?